# ¿Cómo modifico los campos de textos de Form1 desde Form2 en Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, poo

Mi cuestión es la siguiente, tengo un formulario con datos de una persona y varias acciones. Una de ellas es la de abrir la lista (que se lee de una BBDD) y así poder "abrir" un registro guardado. Mi idea es que al seleccionar un registro en este formulario y presionar el botón **SELECCIONAR**, se cierre y todos los valores queden plasmados en el primer formulario.
He tratado de hacerlo con funciones públicas pero no pude hacer que funcione, sin más, muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Para referencias, los nombres de los campos de texto son los siguientes:

textNombre,
textApellido,
textDNI,
textDomNro,
textDomCalle y
textDomLocalidad

[image: Form1]
[image: Form2]

Esta es la función que se encuentra en Form1.cs:

```cs
public void seleccionBBDD(string nom, string ape, string dni, string nro, string cal, string loc)
        {
            textNombre.Text = nom;
            textApellido.Text = ape;
            textDNI.Text = dni;
            textDomNro.Text = nro;
            textDomCalle.Text = cal;
            textDomLocalidad.Text = loc;
        }
```

Esta es la función que se encuentra en Form2.cs y se ejecuta con el botón **SELECCIONAR**:

```cs
private void btnSeleccionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Persona p = new Persona();
        p.seleccionBBDD("Pedro", "Perez", "1234", "42", "Wallaby", "Sidney");
        //Usando parámetros de ejemplo
    }
```

En esta última función no usé los valores de la BBDD porque tengo pensado hacer eso después, ahora sólo quiero poder pasar cualquier valor a los cuadros de texto del otro formulario.

Comment: La pantalla de Persona, aparece después o antes de presionar seleccionar. Si es después, estas creando una instancia de la clase persona, ésta debe de mandar la visualización.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que podes hacer, es pasarle al segundo `Form` el/los `TextBox` que necesitas que se modifiquen en este..

Por ende, en el segundo formulario, deberías tener un constructor que reciba como parámetro el `TextBox` que necesitas modificar

Por ejemplo;

**Formulario 2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    TextBox a;
    public Form2(TextBox a)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.a = a;
    }

    private void btn_modificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a.Text = txt_nuevovalor.Text;
        Close();
    }
}
```

Como se puede ver, recibis en el Constructor un `TextBox`, luego al modificarlo, este se va a modificar en el formulario original.

Para instanciar el segundo formulario, bastaría con:

```
Form2 formulario2 = new Form2(txt_form1);
formulario2.Show();
```

Donde `txt_form1` es el `TextBox` a modificar

Espero haber interpretado bien el problema que planteabas, saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias, de esta manera funciona perfecto!