# Pasar datos de un datagrid en un form2 a campos de texto en un form1, C# con Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un `Form1` que tiene 4 campos de texto: `txt_id`, `txt_rut`, `txt_dv`, `txt_razonSosial`. Y un botón que llama a un `Form2`. En este `Form2` lo que hago es cargar in `DataGrid` con la información de unas razones sociales y sus rutas.

Mi idea es que al dar doble click en algún dato de la fila donde esté la razón social que busco estos datos los envíe a mis 4 campos del `Form1`.

Vi que hay algo similar en el foro en este [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/160617/c%c3%b3mo-modifico-los-campos-de-textos-de-form1-desde-form2-en-visual-studio/160648#160648), pero al leer el código no entiendo la respuesta cuando dicen:

> Como se puede ver, recibis en el Constructor un `TextBox`, luego al modificarlo, este se va a modificar en el formulario original.

Para mi en ese ejemplo el `Form1` es donde el chico tiene los campos de texto y el form2 su listado.

Esto es lo que tengo en mi `Form2`:

```
namespace PasoDato
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {

        // variables
        public static SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection();
        public static SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();

        public static void AbrirConexion()
        {
            string cadena_conexion = @"Data Source=********;Initial Catalog=*****;Integrated Security=False; user id=****;password=*****";
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
            conexion.ConnectionString = cadena_conexion;
            conexion.Open();
        }

        public static void CerrarConexion(){conexion.Close();}

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AbrirConexion();
            comando.Connection = conexion;
            comando.CommandText = "select IdCliente, Rut, Dv,RazonSocial from zf_Clientes order by RazonSocial";
            SqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(reader["IdCliente"].ToString(), reader["Rut"].ToString(), reader["Dv"].ToString(), reader["RazonSocial"].ToString());

            }
            reader.Close();
            CerrarConexion();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            var dataIndexNo = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Index.ToString();
            string cellValue = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            string id = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            string rut = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            string dv = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            string razonSocial = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

            MessageBox.Show("id: "+ id + " Rut: "+rut+" Razón Social: "+razonSocial);

            Form1 datos = new Form1();
            datos.id = id;
            datos.rut = rut;
            datos.dv = dv;
            datos.razon = razonSocial;

            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Ya capturo la información que necesito y lo muestro con un `MessageBox`, ahora lo que no entiendo bien con el ejemplo del link es mandarlos al `Form1` para mostrarlos en los `TextBox` que tengo.

Tengo esto para probar, pero no funciona:

```
namespace PasoDato
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public string id = "";
        public string rut = "";
        public string dv = "";
        public string razon = "";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 formu = new Form2();
            formu.Show();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(id != "")
            {
                txt_id.Text = id;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Si alguien me puede orientar se lo agradecería.

Muchas Gracias

Comment: No uses el evento form1_load.. usa el evento form1_show y tu problema soucionado. Deberias leer sobre cuando se ejecuta cada evento del form

Comment: Y porque tu botton en form1 levanta otro form? para eso, tengo una respuesta, que ya te busco

Comment: mira aca: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/183312/324

Comment: @gbianchi porque así me pidieron que se haga, voy a ver tu link

Comment: Me refiero a un nuevo form.. no a uno que ya existia ;)

Comment: ... siempre lo he hecho así, una mala práctica creo yo. Entendí bien el link que me enviaste pero tengo la duda de dónde iria la línea **FormB.frmPadre = this;** en mi caso

Comment: en el form secundario, para que puedas volver al padre....

Comment: en mi form2, al comienzo, puse *public Form1 frmPadre* y por darte un ejemplo *Form2.frmPadre = this* lo puse dentro de la función dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick, pero me dice "se requiere una referencia de objeto para el campo, método o propiedad no estáticos"

Comment: Sebastián, por favor acepta la edición echa. Tu pregunta no involucra a Visual Studio.

Comment: @MartinFernandez listo, perdón no había visto esa notificación

Comment: Sebastian.. this es el mismo formulario.. tenes un lio de cosas en la cabeza.. te parece si lo hablamos en un chat?

Comment: por favor jajaja, ayer igual me terminé mareando

Comment: pasate por el [chat]

Answer (score 1):

Lo que yo hago para enlazar datos de diferentes formularios.

**FORMULARIO 1**

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public static  Form1 instance=null;
            public string id = "";
            public string rut = "";
            public string dv = "";
            public string razon = "";

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                instance = this;

            }
```

**FORMULARIO 2:**

De esta manera accedes a los controles y variables publicas del formulario 1 (esto lo puedes hacer desde cualquier parte de la aplicación) , puedes acceder o modificar, simulas un proceso reactivo
*Recuerdo que para acceder a los controles de windows form , como por ejemplo un grid este debe esta de manera publica

```
Form1.instance.id 
Form1.instance.rut
Form1.instance.dv 
Form1.instance.razon
```

Answer (score 0):

**Esto es lo que yo haría**

> En el Form con el control a modificar creo esta funcion

```
public void EditarTxt(string _texto)
{
  textbox1.Text = _texto;
}
```

> En el form desde donde quiero manipular el otro form hago esta funcion

```
Class form2
{      

   Form1 frm = new Form();

    void Llamarfunciondelotroform()
    {          
      frm.EditarTxt("texto");
      frm.Show();
    }
}
```

> Explicación

Hago una función que manipule el control que este en ese mismo `Form`. Y después desde el `Form2` creo una nueva instancia del `Form1` que quiero mostrar con el texto que quiero introducir en el `TextBox` del `Form1` llamando a la función que hice.